# Why does lastlog show every user as never having logged in?

Tags: 10.04

Running the `lastlog` command correctly lists all users on my system (same as `/etc/passwd` entries). However all are marked as `**Never logged in**`, including the account I'm currently logged in to. I noticed that my `/var/log/lastlog` file is also empty.

**Edit**: `/var/log/lastlog` is *not* empty, it is a binary file and I was trying to `cat` it, causing nothing to display. `less` displays a binary file.

Does anyone have any insight as to why this would happen? I've never manually edited `/var/log/lastlog`.

**Edit**: Output of `ls -al /var/log/lastlog`:

> -rw-rw-r-- 1 root utmp 292584 2010-05-12 18:14 /var/log/lastlog

Comment: Did you check that you have free space on your /var containing filesystem ? Also please add the output from: ls -la /var/log/lastlog

Comment: @João: Good suggestion, but `df` lists 61% free on that filesystem

Comment: Can you post the output of lastlog? Are you sure they *all* say never logged in? Mine shows that only two accounts have logged in (root, and my own user account). The rest are a bunch of system accounts like pulse, avahi, sshd which have never actually had a log in. Also, /var/log/lastlog shouldn't be empty, but it *is* (according to less) a binary file that requires the lastlog program to parse.

Comment: See my edits: the file is not empty, I was trying to `cat` it. But *all* of the accounts do list Never logged in. `lastlog | grep -v Never` produces an empty output.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Login via gdm is not logged in lastlog. In this respect `ck-history --last` might give you more information.

To test this, go to a console (Ctrl+Alt+F1), log in, then come back to Gnome (Alt+F7) and check the output of `lastlog`.

Comment: You're right - it was my misunderstanding of what `lastlog` does. Thanks.

Comment: The man page isn't very clear about why lastlog won't work on a gdm system, but arrange's use of `ck-history --last` works well, especially if you pipe that to `grep tty7`.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this should be listed as a bug for gdm.  chkrootkit reports a problem whenever /var/log/lastlog is empty:

```
 Checking `z2'...        user xxxx deleted or never logged from lastlog!
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a best solution for me

lastlog | grep -v Never | grep -v Username | awk '{print ENVIRON["HOSTNAME"] ";"$1";"$4" "$5" "$6" "$7" "$8" "$9}'

Regards